# Javascript if null ignore and continue remaining script

Tags: javascript

I have written a line to auto-size section based on inner-window size. It works properly in the page where the section is present. However, when I open other pages - the script stops as there is no such section (#mainSection) in other pages:

```js
window.addEventListener('resize',function(){
    document.getElementById("mainSection").style.height = (window.innerHeight - 86) + 'px';
});
```

Is there a way to ignore this code in other pages and continue the script? Or do it in a way that this script will be run only in the index.php?

Thanks!

Comment: Check whether document.getElementById("mainSection") returns null or a Element object. Documentation link :  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to ignore this code in other pages and continue the
>   script?

You can bind the listener only if `section` is present.

```
document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", function(){ 
   var section = document.getElementById("mainSection"); 
   !!section && window.addEventListener('resize', function(){ 
      section.style.height = (window.innerHeight - 86) + 'px';
   });
});
```

**Note**

- In the above code, it is assumed that once the DOM is loaded `section` will either be present or not.

Comment: ok, the resize is fixed. Could you help me with another one? In $(document).ready i have document.getElementById("mainSection").style.height = (window.innerHeight - 86) + 'px' - to resize it at once when page is loaded. It throws error as well :)

Comment: @Benua which one?

Comment: Added and if statement before this - it works. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="hello"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if(document.getElementById('hello')){
        document.write('done');
    }else{
        document.write('fail');
    }
</script>
```